# Delete Outlook for Windows rule on Outlook for Mac 16

Tags: ms-office

I have configured some rules on Outlook for Windows and do not have access to any Outlook for Windows any more.

I can see rules created by Outlook for Windows (and Outlook on the web) but when trying to open such a rule, I get the error:

> This rule is defined to run only in Outlook for Windows or Outlook on the web. To view or edit this rule, use the same version of Outlook that this rule was created with.

The remove button and the checkbox for those rules are disabled.

Is there any way to remove those rules without using Outlook for Windows?

I have Outlook 16 from Office 365 on macOS.

Comment: If you have access to the webmail interface of that account you can add/delete rules there, *if they were added there.* If the rules were added in a version of Outlook on a Windows PC then you have to run Outlook on a PC to edit them. But then rules created **IN OUTLOOK** should only run when the app is active (EG up and running on a logged in or locked Windows PC.

Comment: @SteveChambers yeah, thanks, just want to clean up stuff that's not needed any more.